# Union partitioned table and view, then query using _PARTITIONTIME not _pt

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a partitioned table called table1 and I need to query it as below:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) = "2021-04-20" 
AND id>50
```

Then I realised there are some missing data in table1 and I have to union with table2 (which is a view) to have complete data so :

```
WITH
  unioned AS(
  SELECT
    id, type, _partitiontime    
  FROM
    `table1`
  WHERE
    _PARTITIONTIME > "2021-04-17" 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    id, type, _pt as _partitiontime,
  FROM
    `table2`
  WHERE
    _pt > "2021-04-17")

  SELECT * FROM unioned
  WHERE _partitiontime = "2021-04-20"
  AND id>50
```

so I get `Invalid field name "_partitiontime".` error. If I write my query as below then it will work:

```
WITH
  unioned AS(
  SELECT
    id, type, _partitiontime as _pt    
  FROM
    `table1`
  WHERE
    _PARTITIONTIME > "2021-04-17" 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    id, type, _pt,
  FROM
    `table2`
  WHERE
    _pt > "2021-04-17")

  SELECT * FROM unioned
  WHERE _pt = "2021-04-20"
  AND id>50
```

but because there are lots of nested queries which are using the above query so I prefer to query the unioned table using _partitiontime not _pt otherwise I have to change lots of codes. Is there any way that the below query works:

```
SELECT * FROM unioned
WHERE _partitiontime = "2021-04-20"
AND id>50
```

Comment: What happens if you run it without giving any of the columns an alias?

Comment: WITH
  unioned AS(
  SELECT
    id, type, _partitiontime    
  FROM
    `table1`
  WHERE
    _PARTITIONTIME > "2021-04-17" 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    id, type, _pt,
  FROM
    `table2`
  WHERE
    _pt > "2021-04-17")

  SELECT * FROM unioned
  --WHERE _partitiontime = "2021-04-20"
  AND id>50

Comment: @d0little do you mean the above comment? it is working if I do not have alias but at the last line WHERE _partitiontime = "2021-04-20"  will give an error and I have to comment it

Comment: table1 is used in many different queries where _partitiontime has many different constraints so I would like to be able to use _partitiontime for unioned table1+table2